# Getting "You do not have permission to view this directory or page." after deployment on azure for react and node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

Hello I have two projects

1. UI project is built over React with pakage.json and it has

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

2. Api project which is built over node.js it has

```
"scripts": {
    "develop": "nodemon src/app",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node src/app"
},
```

I am trying to deploy my project from the visual code extension `Azure App Service`.
I have two azure profiles pre-created for both projects.

1. Deploying method:- Going to `Azure App Service` extension.
2. Right-click on app-service (eg:- For UI) and select "Deploy to Web App".
3. Then select the folder of the UI project.
4. Deployment start and a successfully deployed message pop up.

Also checked on azure `Kudu/DebugConsole`
`site/wwwroot` can see 7 files

1. `node_modules`
2. `public`
3. `src`
4. `.gitignore`
5. `package-lock.json`
6. `package.json`
7. `README.md`

In azure. portal checked

1. Path mapping tab

   1. Virtual path is `"/"`
   2. Physical path is `"site/wwwroot"`
2. Default document is

   1. `Index.js`
   2. `Index.html`

When trying to access from azure URL this message pop-ups
`"You do not have permission to view this directory or page."`

Comment: Is the file list you provided belongs to frontend project ?

Comment: Are you able to run the application in your Local ? If you are able to build application successfully,  try to deploy once again and check all the dependencies are loaded.